# Scraping data from flash web app

Tags: flash, screen-scraping, data-mining

The application in question is the FIFA Ultimate Team web application located at:

http://www.ea.com/uk/football/fifa-ultimate-team

It's essentially a live market where players sell/trade cards. I'm looking to record data such as prices of cards, etc from this application, but I don't really know where to start.

There's a website at http://www.ultimatedb.nl which successfully achieves this, so I know it's possible, but I'm finding it a bit frustrating trying to figure this out.

Does anyone have a good starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the network tab of chrome's developer tools area and look at the requests the movie is making. If it's xml you're in luck, it should be easy to fake the right requests and parse the response. It might be amf format which is a flash-specific format. In that case you have to hope you can find a good library that parses amf for the language you're using.